# Как работает деление с остатком в pow() с отрицательной степенью?

Tags: python, python-3.x

В 3.8 добавили возможность использовать pow() с тремя аргументами при отрицательном втором аргументе. Не понял, как это работает. Объясните, пожалуйста, в максимальных подробностях.

Answer (score 0):

Из документации про [pow](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow):

> If mod is present and exp is negative, base must be relatively prime
> to mod. In that case, pow(inv_base, -exp, mod) is returned, where
> inv_base is an inverse to base modulo mod.

Пример: `pow(2, -3, 17) = pow(9, 3, 17)`. Почему? Потому что `2 * 9 mod 17 = 18 mod 17 = 1`. То есть, `9` и `2` взаимно обратные по модулю `17`. `2**-1 = 9`, `9**-1 = 2`.
Для поиска обратного значения по модулю используется [расширенный алгоритм Евклида](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%95%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0#%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B2_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85).